# Cross domain iframe scripting

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I want to simulate browser in web browser. I need to do some manipulation with page loaded in iframe. I want to find all inputs that contain some specific string in id attribute.  For example find all inputs that contain 'url' in Id attribute and insert value defined in database(using javascript).

I tried to use iframe but i even can't get access to html of page loaded into my iframe. When i try to do it, i get error 'Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL urlA
from frame with URLurlB. Domains, protocols and ports must match.' I read a lot of post and i didn't find any solution to my problem. Only thing that i found is to modify security policy of my browser but i can't ask every user of my application to do it.

I realy need to do it and i will be very grateful for every advice.

Here is link to screen of my application, to better show what i want to do: http://scr.hu/0kos/9jxs6

Comment: There is no solution, it's a cross domain security access control thingy for a reason!

Answer (score 0):

Default browser security policies prevent you from manipulating content from domains that are different than the domain of the page the javascript is located in.  You can read about the "same origin" security restrictions [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).  If that's what you are trying to do, then you're probably not going to be able to do that in a normally configured browser.

A browser plug-in can access any content in the web page, but your viewer would have to download/install the plug-in before this functionality would be enabled.

What it looks like you're trying to do from your screenshot just isn't possible in a normally configured browser and there are very good security reasons for that restriction.

Comment: I don't know too much about plug-in, but if it's the only way to do it, i will use it. It is possible to wirte plugin that will work like iframe and give me possibility to manipulate html code using jquery ?

Comment: @user1285941 - Yes, it is possible with a plug-in to manipulate the DOM in an iframe.  Your viewers would have to install the plug-in and you'd have to write a different plug-in for each browser type you wanted to support.